# how to remove special characters when i paste +1-xxx-xxx-xxxx from another source in android edit text with 10 digits length in android

Tags: android

copy from another source is : +1-541-xxx-3010

when i paste in my edit text i need to get the result as follow : 
541xxx3010

need to remove special characters and also need to remove +1 (country code)
i need to display only 10 digits actual number after removing special chars

```
       @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){         

            String edit = s.toString();
            System.out.println("@@"+edit);
            edit = edit.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
            String result = edit.replaceAll("[|?*<\":>+\\[\\]/'-]","");

            System.out.println(result);
        }
```

Comment: sir you can try subString and take only last 10 character of your string.

Comment: see my answer sir :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try SubString to get only 10 digit from your string.

For E.g. Your String is **+1-541-xxx-3010**. Now as you want you need to remove the + and country code.

```
String phone = "+1-541-xxx-3010"
result = phone.substring(Math.max(phone.length() - 12, 0)).replaceAll("-", ""));
```

From the above code it returns the result like this.

```
Result: 541xxx3010
```

> NOTE : Before apply this code you need to check if your string is not
>   empty or its size is greater than or equal 12.

**OR**

If you don't want to use + and - then why don't you restrict the character using **android:digits** just apply below property in edittext.So it will not allow to enter the character apart from 0-9.

```
android:digits="0123456789"
```

Comment: == PHONE ==:541-xxx-3010 ----   how can i set this result to edittext ?

Comment: You don't need to remove special character because if you do this code it will only takes last 12 character including "-" so it will return only the number with "-". Now if you want to remove this "-" simply replace it with "blank".

Comment: See my Updated answer sir.

Comment: result = phone.substring(Math.max(phone.length() - 12, 0)).replaceAll("[-]","");      ---- in result i get 541xxx3010 . but how can i set this result to edittext  ?

Comment: no need for [ ] this braces you only need to replace "-" so remove this [] braces.

Comment: thanks alot,but its crashing when i enter the number using with my keypad. and it takes more than 10 numbers from keypad . i neeed to restrict only allow to enter 10 digits number and when i paste also i get actual 10 digits number only i want.

Comment: do this code in afterTextChange Listener I already mentioned in note that your string have to greater than or equal to 12 that's why it gives the exception. So check the condition before implement it.

Comment: @LaxmanMarth sir why don't you try this property in edittext android:digits="0123456789" if you set this your keyboard not inserted any other character apart from 0-9 so you don't need to replace + and - etc special character.

Comment: i tried with that but when i paste my number it only giving == 1541xxx == in my edittext. the country code conditon dosent work with that.

Comment: check if condition if(s.length() > 10) {
// Then apply the substring else do nothing.
// Also change the substring use -10 instead of -12
}
this will solve your problem

Comment: thanks !! now its working fine with copy and paste but when i enter from keypad it takes fine upto 10 digits. but it allow 11th digit also.. when i enter 11th digit ..1st digit of our entered number is gone and 11th digit showing in the last.

Comment: Welcome sir :) you can accept the answer if it help you out. That is because after 10 digit it will consider other code as country code that's why it delete the first digit and consider rest 10 as number.

Comment: yeah Btw i need to allow the keypad to enter  10 digits only. i tried with mentioned in xml android.maxLenght = 10 . in this case copy paste not working. can u please try to restrict  enter 10 digits only?

Comment: @LaxmanMarth try this in your activity after findviewbyid of your edit text. edtText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)});

Comment: yea same results as maxLength case.with this  copy and paste thing is not working ,,i.e.. == 1541xxx == (country code remove condition not workng).keypad thing is fine.

Comment: im still facing that  issue..can you please find out any solutiion.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove country code from the string using substring() method,

For remove special character in your case it is "-" you can refer below code snippet

```
String result = inputString.replaceAll("[-]","");
```

Comment: how can i  remove country code when i paste the number.?